# Python - pysqlite or sqlite3 must be installed

Tags: python, sqlite

I have python 2.7.12 installed on my server. I'm using PuTTY to connect to my server. When running my python script I get the following.

> File "home/myuser/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3657, in _connect
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured('pysqlite or sqlite3 must be installed.')
>   peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: pysqlite or sqlite3 must be installed.

I thought sqlite was installed with python 2.7.12, so I'm assuming the issue is something else. Haven't managed to find any posts on here yet that have been helpful.

I am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Peewee will use either the standard library `sqlite3` module or, if you did not compile Python with SQLite, Peewee will look for `pysqlite2`.

The problem is most definitely **not** with Peewee on this one, as Peewee requires a SQLite driver to use the `SqliteDatabase` class... If that driver does not exist, then you need to install it.